# With Delphi and Indy 10.6 how do I keep the TIdTCPServer from dropping a client on read timeout

Tags: delphi, timeout, indy, tcpserver

I've noticed that, when my TCPServer is set for 30 sec read timeout, even though I am handling the EIdReadTimeout in the ServerExecute, and Raise it again there, then handle it in ServerException and show the timeout message there, it still drops that specific client without me telling it to.  On the Client side I handle the EIdReadTimeout and it doesn't drop the server connection.

I want the Server side to do the same thing so I can set the Server timeout at 30 sec and the client at 45 sec so the server can send a timeout message to the Client for a retry and not abort the connection entirely.

Comment: Did you try to not raise it again? The OnExecute loop will continue because the exception did not leave it. Just handle it there (or in your own subroutine) instead of within ServerException.

Comment: MJN is correct. An uncaught exception will stop the thread and trigger the `OnException` event. So catch the exception. Otherwise, don't let a read timeout happen in the first place. Use `Readable()` or `CheckForDataOnSource()` to handle timeouts instead.

Comment: Thanks, the CheckForDataOnSource is what I decided to go with, though it raised another question which I'll pose in another thread ;)